# What is the correct way of aligning this menu?

Tags: html, css, frontend

http://jsfiddle.net/rctdzdsm/

I'm trying to align the menu to the logo.

Do I have to manually margin it till I align correctly?

Or is there a better/proper way of doing this?

Because manually margining till I align it correctly, feels kinda kinda dumb.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #e58b1a;
}
header .logo {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 53px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50px;
}
.menu {
  float: right;
  font-family: arial;
}
.menu li {
  /** Float to the left, helps it become horizontal */
  float: left;
  /** Marigin-right allows you to space your links */
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header class="show-when-loaded" style="height: 108px;">

  <div class="logo">
    <span class="text"> Daz Me Lulz </span>
  </div>


  <div class="menu">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="aboutus.html">About Us </a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="project.html">Projectos De Lulz </a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="involved.html">Get Involved </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a very flexible way of doing this. What if the height of your header changes?

Than you would manually have to align your padding and margins. If you are looking for a more accurate way of doing this, take a look at the different possibilities of displaying elements and aligning them. Even if your menu lives inside an unordert -list. Think of your list being a table and the list items being the table cells. If your elements inherit the height from your header you could easily align them vertically in the middle. Here is a snippet to give you an idea of what i mean.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 108px;
  background-color: orange;
}

header:after {
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  display: table;
  height: inherit;
}

nav li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.logo a {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

nav .nav-bar {
  float: right;
}

nav .nav-bar li {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav role='navigation'>
    <ul class="logo">
      <li>
        <a href="">Daz Me Lulz</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav-bar">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>  
</header>
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the position: relative. because its not needed.
Added the some margins for being aligned better.
Tried to make the li elements wrap, ended up with a none wrapping solution instead.
Made the links text direction from right to left. So they stick to the right side of the screen, without breaking the flow, as float: right does.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #e58b1a;
  min-width: 650px;
}
header .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
}
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: arial;
  min-width: 350px;
  width: calc(100% - 350px);
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.menu ul {
  display: inline;
  direction: rtl;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header class="show-when-loaded">

  <div class="logo">
    <span class="text"> Daz Me Lulz </span>
  </div>


  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="aboutus.html">About Us </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="project.html">Projectos De Lulz </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="involved.html">Get Involved </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CSS tables will help here.

```
header {
  background-color: #e58b1a;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
header .logo {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 53px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu {
  display: table-cell;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #e58b1a;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
header .logo {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 53px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu {
  display: table-cell;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Daz Me Lulz - Providng Renewable Energy to the children of Latin America</title>


<body>

  <header class="show-when-loaded" style="height: 108px;">

    <div class="logo">
      <span class="text"> Daz Me Lulz </span>
    </div>


    <div class="menu">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="aboutus.html">About Us </a>
          </li>
          <li> <a href="project.html">Projectos De Lulz </a>
          </li>
          <li> <a href="involved.html">Get Involved </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </header>




</body>
```